# What is the intuition of this problem about $|f'(x)|$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}$Recently, I met a problem, which says that:

> Given that $f(x)$ have continious derivatives on close interval $[0,2]$, $f(0)=f(2)=0$, $M=\max_{[0,2]} |f(x)|$. Prove that:
>
> > (1) there exists a number $\xi \in (0,2)$, s.t. $|f'(\xi)| \geq M$.

> > (2) If for every $x \in (0,2)$, $|f'(x)|\leq M$, then $M=0$.

I can prove the first problem. However, the second problem makes me mad. So I look up the solution. The proof is here:

> We know that there exists a number $x_0$, s.t. $M=|f(x_0)|=|f(x_0)-f(0)|=|\int_{0}^{x_0}f'(x)dx|\leq\int_{0}^{x_0}|f'(x)|dx\leq\int_{0}^{x_0}Mdx\leq Mx_0$,

> $M=|f(x_0)|=|f(x_0)-f(2)|=|\int_{x_0}^{2}f'(x)dx|\leq\int_{x_0}^{2}|f'(x)|dx\leq\int_{x_0}^{2}Mdx\leq M(2-x_0)$

> So,$M(1-x_0) \leq 0 and  M(1-x_0)\geq 0$. If $x_0 \neq 1$, $M$ is apparently $0$, if $x_0=1$, then $M \leq \int_{0}^{1}|f'(x)|dx \leq M$ and $M \leq \int_{1}^{2}|f'(x)|dx \leq M$, if $M \neq 0$, then it contradicts.

I can understand this solution, but I don't know the intuition or motivation behind this. I don't believe that there exists a solution which has no motivation, but I can't find the motivation behind this problem.

In fact, everytime I meet this kind of problems, I often have no idea, I really think that this kind of problems are hard to solve, can anyone give some advice or some resource about this kind of problems?

Comment: How do the inequalities at the end of the solution lead to a contradiction for the case $x_0=1$? The "tent" function $f(x) = \begin{cases} Mx & \text{if $x \le 1/2$} \\ (2-M)x & \text{if $x > 1/2$}\end{cases}$ doesn't contradict those inequalities. (The reason why this function isn't a real counterexample is because $f'$ doesn't exist at $x=1/2$.)

Comment: For a slightly different take on the same intuition described in the answers below, the edge case is the "tent" centered at $1$, but that's not continuously differentiable at $1$. To make it differentiable, $f$ would have to be "rounded" at $x=1$. In fact, it would have to have $f'(1)=0$ at that point, since that's a local maximum. By continuity, that would mean that $|f'(x)| \lt M/2$ in some neighborhood of $1$, but then the average rate of change on $[0,1]$ would be strictly below $M$ i.e. not enough to reach the maximum.

Comment: sorry, all instances of $1/2$ in my earlier comment should have been $1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The intuition is that to go from $0$ up to $M$ (or vice versa) over less than a unit interval, the average slope has to be greater than $M$.

To make the previous paragraph into a proof, suppose without loss of generality that $f(x_0)=M$ and that $0<x_0\leq1$ (if $x_0>1$, we do a symmetric argument using the endpoint $2$ instead of $0$, and if $f(x_0)<0$ we work with $-f$).

If $x_0<1$, by the Mean Value Theorem,
$$
M=f(x_0)-f(0)=f'(\xi)\,x_0,
$$
so if $M>0$ we get
$$
f'(\xi)=\frac{M}{x_0}>M,
$$
a contradiction. Thus $M=0$.

When $x_0=1$, the only possibility for $f$ is to have $f'=M$ on $(0,1)$ and $f'=-M$ on $(1,2)$. That would contradict the differentiability at $1$.

Comment: I think the case $x_0=1$ has to be handled separately.

Comment: @angryavian: indeed, I left it for the end and I forgot. It's edited in now.

Answer (score 4):

$|f'(x)| \le M \ne 0$ for $x \in (0,2)$ means that the function cannot change values too quickly (the graph of $f$ is never too steep). However, it does need to change quickly enough to go from $0$ to $M$ (or $-M$) and then back to zero. It turns out that the restriction on the steepness of the function is too strict to allow it to reach $M$ or $-M$.

The gist of the solution is that applying the mean value theorem shows that the location of the maximizer (or minimizer) $x_0$ has to satisfy $x_0 \ge 1$ (cannot reach $\pm M$ from $f(0)=0$ quickly enough due to constrained slope) and $x_0 \le 1$ (cannot reach $\pm M$ from $f(2)=0$ quickly enough). So the remaining case to deal with is when $x_0=1$. There is an edge case to be considered (the tent function in my comment) that gets ruled out only because of non-differentiability at $x=1$.

Comment: @dxiv oops thank you